# How do I change some routes in Django Project after login?

Tags: python, django, web, web-applications

Let me explain with an example.
Like when we first open www.coursera.org we get to their homepage. Then we login. After we login the session starts and we are redirected to main course dashboard. but if we see URl it is www.coursera.org so now the home route has chanmged from homepage to say dashboard. 
Now in django i can redirect to project.com/dashboard from project.com/login but what i want is after login the user should not have access to homepage at any route.
So i want to change project.com/   which before login showed homepage to now showing the dashboard view simply change the view function linked to project.com/ route

I hope I explained my question correctly. 
Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its easily doable in urlconf. If you use function based views, just check if user is authenticated and if he is, then call the view function for dashboard, if not then display the front page.

For CBVs probably use UserPassesTestMixin and set the test_func to redirect authenticated users to dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Django's built-in `login_required` decorator, which does exactly what you want. For example, given that `settings.LOGIN_URL == "/login"`, that you decorate `/foo` and you try to access that URL without being logged in, it will redirect you to `/login/?next=/foo`. After you log in, it will redirect you back to `/foo`.

> **login_required**(*redirect_field_name='next', login_url=None*)
>
> [...]
>
> - If the user isn’t logged in, redirect to `settings.LOGIN_URL`, passing the current absolute path in the query string. Example: `/accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/`.
> - If the user is logged in, execute the view normally. The view code is free to assume the user is logged in.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

Comment: Thanks for helping I really couldn't get this working in my case but maybe helpful for others.